# Conditional join in r

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I would like to conditionally join two data tables together:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

key.table <- 
  data.table(
    out = (0:10)/10,
    keyz = sort(runif(11))
  )

large.tbl <- 
  data.table(
    ab = rnorm(1e6),
    cd = runif(1e6)
  )
```

according to the following rule: match the smallest value of `out` in `key.table` whose `keyz` value is larger than `cd`. I have the following:

```
library(dplyr)
large.tbl %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(out = min(key.table$out[key.table$keyz > cd]))
```

which provides the correct output. The problem I have is that the `rowwise` operation seems expensive for the `large.tbl` I am actually using, crashing it unless it is on a particular computer. Are there less memory-expensive operations? The following seems slightly faster, but not enough for the problem I have.

```
large.tbl %>%
    group_by(cd) %>%
    mutate(out = min(key.table$out[key.table$keyz > cd]))
```

This smells like a problem with a `data.table` answer, but the answer does not have to use that package.

Comment: I upvoted your question because everyone else did ^ ^.

Comment: I think you should attempt a solution first if you think there's a potential solution using a particular package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
setkey(large.tbl, cd)
setkey(key.table, keyz)
key.table[large.tbl, roll = -Inf]
```

See `?data.table`>`roll`:

> Applies to the last join column, generally a date but can be any ordered variable, irregular and including gaps. If `roll=TRUE` and `i`'s row matches to all but the last `x` join column, and its value in the last `i` join column falls in a gap (including after the last observation in `x` for that group), then the prevailing value in `x` is rolled forward. This operation is particularly fast using a modified binary search. The operation is also known as last observation carried forward (LOCF). Usually, there should be no duplicates in `x`'s key, the last key column is a date (or time, or datetime) and all the columns of `x`'s key are joined to. A common idiom is to select a contemporaneous regular time series (`dts`) across a set of identifiers (`ids`): `DT[CJ(ids,dts),roll=TRUE]` where `DT` has a 2-column key (`id,date`) and `CJ` stands for cross join. When `roll` is a positive number, this limits how far values are carried forward. `roll=TRUE` is equivalent to `roll=+Inf`. When `roll` is a negative number, values are rolled backwards; i.e., next observation carried backwards (NOCB). Use `-Inf` for unlimited roll back. When roll is `"nearest"`, the nearest value is joined to.

(to be fair I think this could go for some elucidation, it's pretty dense)

Comment: To be fair, I am working on detailed [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944)... which I thought was quite known to data.table users.

Comment: I know, consider this a soft nudge ;-)

Comment: I suspect this is the correct answer. But after reading the documentation I still don't fully understand this method.

Comment: Understand now. I found this helpful http://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/

Comment: @Hugh very cool. I wonder if there's not a way to add this to the documentation...

Answer (score 5):

If `key.table$out` is also sorted as is in your toy example, following would work

```
ind <- findInterval(large.tbl$cd, key.table$keyz) + 1
large.tbl$out <- key.table$out[ind]
head(large.tbl)
#             ab         cd out
#1: -0.928567035 0.99473795  NA
#2: -0.294720447 0.41107393 0.5
#3: -0.005767173 0.91086585 1.0
#4:  2.404653389 0.66491244 0.8
#5:  0.763593461 0.09590456 0.1
#6: -0.799009249 0.50963409 0.5
```

If `key.table$out` is not sorted,

```
ind <- findInterval(large.tbl$cd, key.table$keyz) + 1
vec <- rev(cummin(rev(key.table$out)))
large.tbl$out <- vec[ind]
```